# How to specialize template function with template types

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

Is it possible to specialize a template function for template types? I don't know if my terminology is correct, so I'll provide a simple sample with what I want to achieve:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void f()
{
    std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void f<std::string>()
{
    std::cout << "string" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void f<std::vector<T>>()
{
    std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    f<double>();
    f<std::string>();
    f<std::vector<int>>();

    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't compile. VS2013 gives me

> error C2995: 'void f(void)' : function template has already been defined

on this function:

```
template<typename T>
void f<std::vector<T>>()
{
    std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
}
```

How may I achieve this behavior? It's very important to have `type f(void)` signature. Is this code falling into partial specialization for functions(forbidden in C++)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't partially specialize template function, but you can for template class.
So you can forward your implementation to a dedicated class.
Following may help: (https://ideone.com/2V39Ik)

```
namespace details
{
    template <typename T>
    struct f_caller
    {
        static void f() { std::cout << "generic" << std::endl; }
    };

    template<>
    struct f_caller<std::string>
    {
        static void f() { std::cout << "string" << std::endl; }
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct f_caller<std::vector<T>>
    {
        static void f() { std::cout << "vector" << std::endl; }
    };
}

template<typename T>
void f()
{
    details::f_caller<T>::f();
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me why this is falling in partial function specialization? Thank you!

Comment: This would be better if `f_caller` was a simple __functor__. Still - +1.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to be as close as possible to the original code is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct f {
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
struct f<std::string> {
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "string" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct f<std::vector<T> > {
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    f<double>()();
    f<std::string>()();
    f<std::vector<int> >()();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, +1:) I will use details/private implementation because the code is more clear there:)