# How to specialize templated method within class template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'm trying to do some Resolution struct which simply holds my width_ and height_ of screen.
I will use it a lot in certain ways, and some methods will require a vector like data and some will require and internal structure-like data.

> Example:

```c
template<typename InternalType>
struct Resolution
{
 InternalType width_;
 InternalType height_;

 std::vector<InternalType> vectorRepr()
 {
  return std::vector<InternalType>{width_, height_};
 };

 Vector2 vectorRepr()
 {
  return Vector2{width_, height_};
 };

 // maybe some other overloadings of vectorRepr()
}
```

Above example is NOT working, as vectorRepr is overloaded badly.

What I want to achive is to have in Resolution struct encapsulated methods to return me internal state in different data types. Template specialization might come in handy for this, but I'am having a hard time joining the idea of both Resolution templating and vectorRepr templating.

For me it looks similar as partial template specialization.

Close up to std::vector return type:

```
template<> // <- this is a specialization for vectorRepr
std::vector<InternalType> vectorRepr<std::vector>() 
{
 // but here, vector should know the InternalType, to embed it.
 // so the InternalType is not specialized.
 return std::vector<InternalType>{width_, height_};
}
```

Here I've found interesting example (but it is lacking a member attributes to return):
[How to specialize template function with template types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810293/how-to-specialize-template-function-with-template-types)

I am aware it can be done easy in different way, but at this point I'm just to curious.

Is it achivable ?

Playground:

https://godbolt.org/z/bE49vv3Ms

Comment: What C++ version? `requires` from C++20 makes this easier.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add c++17 tag, but I'll dig into Your sugestion tho.

Comment: For C++17 you can make a single function with `auto` return type (or `std::conditional_t<...>`), and `if constexpr` inside. I believe making separate functions would require all of them to be templates (unless you use C++20 `requires`), or be moved to base classes (then selecting a base class based on template argument).

Comment: Okey, internally spliting function behaviour based on provided type is something, but https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-specialization makes this beautifull split for SRP principle. Looks like I can't have everything.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/rvKreMb7n ? You can't explicitly specialize in C++ templated typenames like T<A> etc.

Comment: @vikAy similar, but nor really. Now `Resolution` have two implementations that I would need to somehow hast between to get different representation of internal state, or just copy constructor.

Comment: @Wiktoor https://godbolt.org/z/8M8bMfeKd Then you must "explicitly specialize by names" or have different api with a data-structure as in-parameter

Comment: Are you somehow forced to use a specific name? Otherwise two functions `vectorRepr()` and `Vector2Repr()` would work fine. In the linked example, I see no advantage of using `f<string>()` over `f_string()`, "just because you can"?.

Comment: @BoP it is convinient to have in interface a one function responsible for retreving data in specific type. It is highly probable that having vector2Repr and vectorRepr and event arrayRepr would be confusing and hard to remamber which one does what. Explicitly specifing type as template removes this confusion and makes interface easier to work with.

Comment: Something along [these lines](https://godbolt.org/z/do4bzG1Mq), perhaps.

Comment: Or [this](https://godbolt.org/z/s3brPxG69), in fact. For the types you want it to work with, you don't need any kind of specialization in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example shown, I don't see a need for any specialization, partial or otherwise. This is sufficient:

```
template <typename Ret>
Ret vectorRepr() {
  return {width_, height_};
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/966o3czv4)